# Steps to create a new data set using SQL option in drools workbench installed on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, drools, derby

I installed derby database to create a new data set in drools workbench.
Creating a new data set in drools workbench using SQL option requires JNDI path so
I configured the data source on Tomcat by modifying the server.xml and web.xml and restarted the server. After restarting the server, kie workbench is throwing exception.

Comment: What is your question? Is it about the exception? What exception is it throwing?